# How to merge trees (and sum counts) using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, tree

Say I have these classes:

```
public class Option
{
    public int OptionID { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say this would be my result after adding some `Product` objects into a `List<Product>`

`2x Product 1
       OptionID 1
       OptionID 1
       OptionID 2
       OptionID 2`

`2x Product 1
       OptionID 1
       OptionID 1
       OptionID 2
       OptionID 2`

How can I convert these results into a single result using LINQ (lambda), where `IsSelected = true`?

`4x Product 1
    4x OptionID 1
    4x OptionID 2`

Comment: Your final objective isn't possible with your current `ChartItems` class.

Comment: In your `ChartItems` class, does `Quantity` represent the quantity of a `Product` or of an `Option`?

Comment: In your `ChartItems` class, is the `List<int> OptionID` just a list of all selected `OptionID` values.

Comment: -1 If you change your question after two people have provided good answers, then it's best to mark one of the answers as the correct answer to your original question, and then to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Konrad's answers is close, it doesn't quite provide what you're wanting. It needs to use anonymous types and two groups.

Here's a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/v907me and its most relevant code.

```
var query = products.GroupBy(p => p.ProductID, (key, values) => new
{
    ProductID = key, 
    Quantity = values.Sum(v => v.Quantity), 
    Options = values
        .SelectMany(v => v.Options.Where(o => o.IsSelected))
        .GroupBy(o => o.OptionID, (k, v) => new
        {
            OptionID = k,
            Quantity = v.Count()
        })
});
```

Comment: @DeMama While I was able to add the `IsSelected` filter, I'm not sure about what your requirements are for grafting the result into your `ChartItems` class. That part of your question is opaque to me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this is quite typical [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549393(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.ProductID, 
                         (key, values) => new Product()
                         {
                            ProductID = key,
                            Quantity = values.Sum(p => p.Quantity),
                            Options = values.SelectMany(p => p.Options).ToList()
                         }).ToList();
```

so `result` is a `List<Product>` containing products merged with respect to the `ProductID`.