# Combine duplicate selections into a single result

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, list

In addition to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578427/how-to-merge-trees-and-sum-counts-using-linq), I still have no concrete solution to my problem.

I have 2 classes like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Options = new List<Option>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public int SubID { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
    public int ListBoxID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Which are used in a list like this:

```
List<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

[image]

When a user selects a product on the left (which are always with the same properties), it's internal `List<Optie>` will get loaded in 4 different `ListBox's`, Filtered by `ListBoxID`.

Now, if a user selects the same options in 2 products, how can I convert them into one result using linq?

e.g. 4 identical products are loaded, user selects the same options for 2 products, then my result would be:

`2x Product
    2x lookbrood
    2x ollema
    2x fitness broodje
    2x testtest`

If the 2 other products have different selections, these might be the result for them:

`2x Product
    2x ciabatta broodje
    2x ollema
    2x slagroom
    2x smos`

I always need the quantity loaded into `Products`:
e.g.: 6 products are loaded, then my combinations can be:

`3x Product
    3x ciabatta broodje
    3x ollema
    3x slagroom
    3x smos`

`3x Product
    3x Some other option 1
    3x Some other option 2
    3x Some other option 3
    3x Some other option 4`

or

`2x Product
    2x Some option 1
    2x Some option 2
    2x Some option 3
    2x Some option 4`

`2x Product
    2x Some other option 1
    2x Some other option 2
    2x Some other option 3
    2x Some other option 4`

`2x Product
    2x Some other option 1
    2x Some other option 2
    2x Some other option 3
    2x Some other option 4`

This is the best explanation I can give, I hope the image helps.

Comment: It might be clearer if you could give an example of 2 `Product` with their `Optie` (options?) and what the result should look like if those 2 `Product` are selected. What should be the type of the final result? Should it be a single `Product`? A `List<Product>`? How are the `Optie` supposed to be combined?

Comment: Argh... why do you mix languages like that? You have a property called IsSelected (nice, English name)... and then a bunch of non-english properties (including the class name). If you ever get a coder from another country your code will be hell to work with for him / her. Other than that, I can't quite make out what you're trying to do. :|

Comment: @MattBurland Updated my question, it's a complicated thing, I know..

Comment: @Shaamaan That's why I develop on my own ;-), but I updated the property names for you

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `GroupBy`?. This will group `Optie`s with the same ID, and give you the number of them.

```
Product.Opties
    .GroupBy(x => new {
        x.ListBoxID, x.Naam
    })
    .Select(x => 
    new { 
        ListBoxID = x.Key.ListBoxID,
        Naam = x.Key.Naam,
        Count = x.Count()
    })
```

[More info on GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)